# Convolution vs. Conv2d function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

In Tesnorflow, there are some functions for convolution networks which are dubbed `conv1d`, `conv2d`, `conv3d`, and `convolution`. As mentioned in the documentation for `convolution`:

> Computes sums of N-D convolutions (actually cross-correlation).

Also, for the other functions, we have the similar explanation which is related to their dimensions.

The **question** is if we use `convolution` for 2d data instead of `conv2d` (also for 1d and 3d), Will get a different performance in running time or not? (in general on CPU or GPU version).

## Update

As I found the `convolution` is restricted for `N` between 1 and 3, the answer to the question could be trivial!

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't get any penalty. `convolution` [checks the dimension of your convolution and call the appropriate specialization](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L102), if applicable.